# understanding implementing Java Extended Classes

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm currently learning Java and I've been given the task of understanding OOP.
I understand the theory of classes, but I have a question on implementation.

Take the following code as example:

```
class Vehicle {
  private String engine;
  private int wheels;
  private int seats;
  private int fuelTank;
  private String lights;

  public Vehicle() {
    this.engine = "petrol";
    this.wheels = 4;
    this.seats = 4;
    this.fuelTank = 35;
    this.lights = "LED";

  }

  public Vehicle(String engine, int wheels, int seats, int fuelTank, String lights) {

    this.engine = engine;
    this.wheels = wheels;
    this.seats = seats;
    this.fuelTank = fuelTank;
    this.lights = lights;
  }

  public String getEngine() {
    return engine;
  }

  public int getWheels() {
    return wheels;
  }

  public int getSeats() {
    return seats;
  }

  public int getFueTank() {
    return fuelTank;
  }

  public String getLights() {
    return lights;
  }

}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  private String steering;
  private String musicSystem;
  private String airConditioner;
  private String fridge;
  private String entertainmentSystem;

  public Car() {
    super();
    this.steering = "Power Steering";
  }

  public Car(String steering, String engine, int wheels, int seats, int fueTank, String lights) {
    super(engine, wheels, seats, fueTank, lights);
    this.steering = steering;
  }

  public String getSteering() {
    return steering;
  }
}

class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car car = new Car("Power steering", "deisel", 4, 4, 40, "LED");

    System.out.println("Steering: " + car.getSteering());
    System.out.println("Engine type: " + car.getEngine());
    System.out.println("Number of seats: " + car.getSeats());
    System.out.println("Fuel tank capacity: " + car.getFueTank());
    System.out.println("Head lamp type: " + car.getLights());
    System.out.println("Number of wheels: " + car.getWheels());
  }

}
```

I understand here that you can create a `Vehicle` object by either using the default constructor or the parameterized constructor. I can also do the same with a `Car` object that extends from `Vehicle`. I understand that by using `super()` in the default constructor it will use the default constructor in `Vehicle` as well as the `Car` objects steering variable default. The same with the parameterize constructor using the `super(args)`.

I'm having an issue understanding how I can hardcode wheels in each extended class of vehicle.

To explain more, I don't want to have to include wheels in the constructor when creating a `Car` object. I want it to default to 4. Also, if I were to create a `Bike` object extended from `Vehicle`, I want the wheels variable to default to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get use of your super class attributes please change their access modifier type to be protected, otherwise you wont be able to use them directly in your child classes.

Then you can use a IIB (Instance Initialization Block) to define your wheels variable value for each different child class.

### Sample solution:

#### Vehicle.java

```
public class Vehicle{

    //attributes with protected access modifier
    protected String engine;
    protected int wheels;
    protected int seats;
    protected int fuelTank;
    protected String lights;

    public Vehicle(){//No-args constructor

    }

    
     public Vehicle(String engine, int seats, int fuelTank, String lights) {

         this.engine = engine;
         this.seats = seats;
         this.fuelTank = fuelTank;
         this.lights = lights;

    }

     public Vehicle(String engine, int wheels, int seats, int fuelTank, String lights) {

         this.engine = engine;
         this.wheels = wheels;
         this.seats = seats;
         this.fuelTank = fuelTank;
         this.lights = lights;
     }

       
}
```

#### Car.java

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{

     private String steering;
     private String musicSystem;
     private String airConditioner;
     private String fridge;
     private String entertainmentSystem;

    {//IIB block to initialize wheels with default value

        wheels = 4;//Defining the wheels variable 


    }

     public Car(String steering,String engine,int seats,int fuelTank,String lights) 
     {//Overloaded constructor
         super(engine,seats,fuelTank,lights);
         this.steering = steering;

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as as follows.

```
private final String steering; // final = constant, will not change.

public Car(String steering, String engine, int seats, int fueTank, String lights) {
    super(engine, 4 /*wheels*/, seats, fueTank, lights);
    this.steering = steering;
}

public Car(String steering, String engine, int fueTank, String lights) {
    this(steering, engine, 4 /*seats*/, fueTank, lights);
}
```

As you see here, several constructors and many parameters can become cumbersome.

Sometimes it is better to have setters for the special fields.